# Running a shell script via Jenkins running on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, bash, shell, jenkins, ssh

I have wrote a shell script which uses Linux specific commands and is hosted on a RHEL7 EC2 instance, this isn't a problem as it can be ran from any Unix machine.

How can I create a Jenkins job which will successfully run this script? The script works fine on any Unix machine, however I can't seem to find a way to run the command via a Jenkins job which is hosted in a Windows Server 2008 environment.

So far I have tried adding the SSH plug-ins for Jenkins (got an error regarding my private key, however I have confirmed it is correct) and I have tried remotely connecting to the Linux server via PuTTY command line (plink) and passing through the username/password followed by the script I'd like to be ran yet no luck.

I was just wondering if anybody has encountered a similar challenge and could guide me down the right path, I've spent hours researching different methods/configurations with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Note: I have also tried locally installing Cygwin and running the script that way but it didn't work, probably due to my own configuration - However, it does seem overkill for my scenario.

Comment: You could make the server a jenkins agent and pin the job to that agent.

Comment: I've tried this, it complains about my private key - However, the private key is correct. I'm using the private key AWS provides me to SSH into my EC2 instance, is this correct?

Comment: Here is my error message from attempting to log in to the agent via the Jenkins console:
`code` Connection timed out: connect
ERROR: Unexpected error in launching a slave. This is probably a bug in Jenkins.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection is not established!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working in the end, I went back to the agent idea after @jordanm's comment - I couldn't get it to work via username/private key authentication, however a simple username/password combination worked fine.

I set up a Jenkins user on my remote machine and created it a root directory which I defined in Jenkins, adding the build-step into my job and worked first time.